# After Facebook Login (javascript sdk) - How do i create a user session in Spring-Security?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using:
- Facebook-JavaScript-SDK (for login)
- Angular-JS (front end)
- Spring-Security (server security layer)
- Spring MVC (server MVC)

User's can log-into my web app by 
**(A)** either using Facebook login (implemented in javascript FB SDK) OR 
**(B)** via normal username/password form.

In case of (B)
i do a Form Post with fields:

```
j_username
j_password

to /j_spring_security_check (Spring Security)
```

This works fine.

But in case of (A), after the user has logged in via FB (in front-end),
 
What do i need to do to have Spring Security create the Session for the user? 
All i have is facebook user's email with me at this point, and Server is unaware of this login in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

After successful login with Face Book,you should make AJAX request to your back-end API and make database entry about the Face book authentication for the user.

1)You need to implement UserDetailsService from Spring-Security

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userEmail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // check for Facebook authentication(DB Entry)
    // fetch user details and roles from db using e-mail
    SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roles);

    UserDetails usd = new User(userId, userId, grantedAuths);
    return usd;

}

}
```

2) Implement custom authentication provider

```
@Component("customAuthenticationProvider")

public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String userId = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        UserDetails userFromDB = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userId);

        if (userFromDB != null) {

            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            for (GrantedAuthority auth : userFromDB.getAuthorities()) {
                grantedAuths.add(auth);
            }

            if (grantedAuths.size() != 0) {
                System.out.println("user:" + userId + " got auth from custom auth provider");
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userFromDB, password, grantedAuths);

            } else {
                throw new DisabledException("No roles assigned");
            }

        }

        throw new DisabledException("User or password incorrect");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

3)  Login controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login",           )
public ResponseEntity<Object> fbLogin(@RequestParam String userEmail,  HttpServletRequest request) {

  UserDetails   userDetails=customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userid);

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userid);
            token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
            Authentication authentication = this.customAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(token);

}
}
```

4) Spring Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;  

 @Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
}
```